# Не выводятся данные с сервера на страницу

Tags: reactjs

Кто может подсказать в чем проблема? Ошибок в консоли нет.

```js
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);
 
  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    setUsers(res.data)
    console.log(res.data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-3xl mb-8">Users</h1>
      
        {users.map((user) => {
          <li>{user.name}</li>;
        })}
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего, это [ответ на ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499871/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%85%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5-map-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0/1499874#1499874)

Comment: Сделай так `{users.map((user) => <li>{user.name}</li>)}`. Или замени фигурные скобки вокруг `<li>{user.name}</li>` на круглые.

Comment: спасибо чуваки, весь день голову ломал.